# как изменить цвет текста в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

типо такого:

[image: типа такого:]

не обращайте внимания на этот текст, он нужен  чтобы пропустить вопрос

Comment: Никак. Стоковые клиенты не умеют в разные цвета.

Answer (score 3):

ты взял фотку с темы где все подробно описывается. В чем прикол?
https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter2.html
(если ты не понял как это сделать из статьи то тебе надо установить библиотеку `pip install emoji` и выполнить этот код

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.ANY)
async def unknown_message(msg: types.Message):
    message_text = text(emojize('Я не знаю, что с этим делать :astonished:'),
                        italic('\nЯ просто напомню,'), 'что есть',
                        code('команда'), '/help')
    await msg.reply(message_text, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего "команда" это ссылка. И основной цвет в теме телеграма красный.

Answer (score 0):

Такое, к сожалению, невозможно. Даже используя HTML со стилями CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть полный код этого урока (https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter2.html) и станет все понятно.

marlin09 не совсем прав, что надо установить библиотеку emoji. Там импортируется это: from aiogram.utils.markdown import text, bold, italic, code

Код здесь: https://github.com/mahenzon/aiogram-lessons/blob/master/lesson-02/bot.py

PS И это не изменит цвет текста. В примере картинки красный текст просто отформатирован как код и у них клиент отображает его красным (в стандартном клиенте он синий).